# Android Studio Class name green?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What does it mean when the class name is green instead of redish?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

It is related with `Version Control`. You have `Enabled Version Control` on your project:

- **Green** means that the file exists in `repository` but there are changes made on that.
- **Red** means that the file is not added to the `repository`

Comment: @james brown You should accept the answer if it helped you.